# Can I safely delete items in my "downloaded apps" folder?

Tags: file-management

I want to free up space on my phone and was wondering if I can delete items in my "downloaded apps" folder.
  I know on my computer there is a difference between the downloaded file and the installed application and that once the application is installed the downloaded file can be deleted.  But I wasn't sure about my phone.

Comment: What is this "downloaded apps" folder? Where do you see this name?

Answer (score 1):

**Direct answer**: Yes you can safely delete the apk you download once it is installed.

**Developed answer**: Any apk file you download goes to the external storage (either external sdcard or fuse-mounted internal storage that appears as external storage). Installing an apk is just a matter of copying it to internal storage (inside a folder within /data partition). so once installed, the apk becomes redundant, and it is safely to remove the one you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder you are refering has the apks of the apps you have downloaded then they can be deleted since they are not requied for the app to function.

Answer (score -1):

When I attempt a delete of a file in the downloaded apps folder on 5 June 2017 on my Galaxy Prevail, a box appears advising that the app will be uninstalled.